How to Build ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with COMReference (Concerto4xSecurity) in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project in Azure DevOps Pipeline. The project includes a COMReference (Concerto4xSecurity) which is library of .Net framework that is required during build and runtime. However, I'm encountering the following error when trying to build the project:

error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the
.NET Core version of MSBuild.

My project needs to build with COMReference (Concerto4xSecurity), not exclude it.
I have tried the following approaches:

Used MSBuild tasks instead of dotnet build.
Tried conditional exclusion during .NET Core builds.
Enabled and disabled EnableComHosting.

Despite these attempts, I still encounter the same error during the build pipeline
Is there a recommended way to build a .NET Core 8 Web API project with COMReference in Azure DevOps Pipeline
